# Drupal 8: Automatically content synchronizing between 2 sites

Tags: module, drupal, synchronization

I want to share content and media between multiple drupal sites. I want to prepare content on a staging instance and push it to the production environment with a click of a button or by any configuration setting between 2 sites. Distribute content automatically to all connected sites or provide your editors with a simple interface for importing content and media.

I already used the drupal [content sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync) module, in this module sync content process is done manually between sites by exporting and importing all site content.

Is there any module or way to sync content automatically between multiple drupal sites?

Comment: For drupal 6/7 there were the [deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) module and its submodules, but for drupal 8+ it has been completely redesigned and you will have to use the following _incomplete_ modules : workspace, replication, relaxed (RELAXed Web Services), optionally (and cautiously) multiversion, and deploy (mostly for the UI). By incomplete I mean that none of these modules have a stable release for d8+, there are all stuck in beta (no update since 2+ years). You can get it to work though.

Comment: Check these live demos [here](https://youtu.be/tgmypdEOEVs) and [here](https://youtu.be/ibBX2cHdhu8). The deploy documentation for d8+ is [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/deploy).